# Copy and paste multiple times and loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem in writing a code to copy and paste multiple times.

I have 2 sheets, where in sheet 1 I have 160 Rows and 3 columns.
I need to copy each row and paste 15 times in sheet 2.

can anyone help me to sort it out.

Comment: Sub CopyData()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim Num As Integer
Num = InputBox("How many Times")
lRow = 1

Do While Num > 0

Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(4, "C")).Copy
Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + 1, "C")).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

lRow = lRow + 3
Num = Num - 1

Loop

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1:A169").Select

End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you keep your three columns as you stated and the headers in row 1, you achieve what you say by changing the ranges dynamically in a simple for loop

```
Sub copy_15()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim wS2 As Range
Set wS2 = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion

wS2.ClearContents

'Copy headers
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C1").Copy
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial

End With

Dim lastRow1 As Long: lastRow1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow1

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Copy
    
Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastRow2 + 1 & ":C" & lastRow2 + 15).PasteSpecial

Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Return Repeated Rows in Another Worksheet

```vb
Sub RepeatRows()
 
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sFirstRowAddress As String = "A2:C2"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim RepeatCount As Variant
    Dim msg As Long
    
    Do
        RepeatCount = InputBox("How many Times")
        If IsNumeric(RepeatCount) Then
            If Len(RepeatCount) = Len(Int(RepeatCount)) Then
                If RepeatCount > 0 Then Exit Do
            End If
        End If
        msg = MsgBox("Not a valid entry.", vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Try again?")
        If msg = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    Loop
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    
    Dim sData As Variant
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim cCount As Long
    
    With sws.Range(sFirstRowAddress)
        Dim lCell As Range: Set lCell = .Resize(sws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
        srCount = lCell.Row - .Row + 1
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        If srCount + cCount = 2 Then ' one cell
            ReDim sData(1 To 1, 1 To 1): sData(1, 1) = .Value
        Else ' multiple cells
            sData = .Resize(srCount).Value
        End If
    End With
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = srCount * RepeatCount
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        For n = 1 To RepeatCount
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(dr, c) = sData(sr, c)
            Next c
        Next n
    Next sr
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, cCount)
        .Resize(drCount).Value = dData
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount).Clear
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Rows repeated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```